# Вывести дату в формате гг.мм.дд

Tags: javascript

```
function formatDate(date) {

  var a = new Date( date.getFullYear() );
  var b = new Date( date.getMonth() );
  var c = new Date( date.getDate() );

 while ( a.length >= 2 ) {
    a[i] = ''; // 2014 -> 014 - > 14
    i++;
}

 if (b <= 9) {
    var b = '0' + b; // 00 число с двумя знаками
}

//та же самая проверка для переменной c*

 return a * 1 + '.' + b * 1 + '.' + c * 1;
} 

  var d = new Date(2014, 0, 30); 
alert( formatDate(d) ); // должно вывести 14.00.30
```

Comment: Вопроса не будет?)

Comment: Даже не знаю с чего начать громить этот безумный код…

Comment: Наверное надо начать с вопроса что в переменных a, b и c по замыслу автора и в реальности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date);
  var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  var day = '' + d.getDate();
  var year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

console.log(formatDate('5,11,99'));
console.log(formatDate('Sun May, 11, 99'));
console.log(formatDate('05, 11, 1999'));
```